# How does NOS determine invitees for electoral debates?

Tags: election, netherlands

In the [NOS election debates](http://nos.nl/artikel/2156180-loting-nos-verkiezingsdebatten-verricht.html) for the [Dutch General election, 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_general_election,_2017), invited parties include all 11 parties that gained seats at the [previous elections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_general_election,_2012) as well as the new parties Nieuwe Wegen, VoorNederland, and DENK.  How are the latter three invitees determined?  In polls, DENK [polls at 0–2 seats](http://peilingwijzer.tomlouwerse.nl/), VoorNederland at 0–1 seats, and Forum voor Democratie at 0–1 seats.  Forum voor Democratie was not invited; Nieuwe Wegen was; I have not seen any opinion poll in which it would enter parliament (threshold 0.67%).  The linked NOS article states invitees are *voor de helft bepaald door het huidige aantal zetels in de Tweede Kamer en voor de andere helft door de Peilingwijzer van 1 februari*, which means determined half by the current seat number in de Tweede Kamer and half for the other by the meta-poll Peilingwĳzer.  However, neither Nieuwe Wegen, VoorNederland, or DENK [are currently in parliament](https://www.tweedekamer.nl/kamerleden/fracties), and Nieuwe Wegen has not even appeared in Peilingwĳzer, so that does not explain why Nieuwe Wegen was invited but Forum voor Democratie was not.

Based on what criteria does NOS decide what 14 parties to invite to the election debate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, neither Nieuwe Wegen, VoorNederland, or DENK are currently in parliament, [..]

They are, but under a different name.

VoorNederland is founded by Joram van Klaveren and Louis Bontes. Both were originally elected in Parliament to represent PVV. Currently in Parliament under the name ["Groep Bontes/van Klaveren"](https://www.tweedekamer.nl/kamerleden/fracties/bontes-vanklaveren).

DENK is founded by Tunahan Kuzu and Selçuk Öztürk. Both were originally elected in Parliament to represent PvdA. Currently in Parliament under the name ["Groep Kuzu/Öztürk"](https://www.tweedekamer.nl/kamerleden/fracties/grk%C3%B6).

Nieuwe Wegen is founded by Jacques Monasch. He was originally elected in Parliament to represent PvdA. Currently in Parliament under the name ["Monasch"](https://www.tweedekamer.nl/kamerleden/fracties/monasch).

No member of the current Parliament is linked to the Forum voor Democratie.

Comment: I see — does that mean NOS grants any parliamentarian who splits off, starts their own party, and then participates in the elections, access to the debates?

Comment: @gerrit In this election cycle, it looks that way. But the rules are flexible enough to make an exception when NOS wants to.

Comment: Hmm, but isn't the [Vrĳzinnige Partĳ](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vrijzinnige_Partij) in parliament under the name [Groep Klein](https://www.tweedekamer.nl/kamerleden/fracties/klein)?  Then why Nieuwe Wegen / Monasch but not Vrĳzinnige Partĳ / Klein?

Comment: I guess the second part of the rule, the polls, comes into action. But I understand the decision. I think it's logical to invite all 11 established parties. Then add DENK (as a party aimed at minorities, and having lots of media attention). Add an alternative to PVV, so either VNL or FvD (in this case VNL). That's 13. For one segment of the debat, people are paired, so there is space for a 14th. I guess Monasch' connections made him the 14th, but I see no obvious reason to pick him over the others left out.